# RNDC is not reloading my ACL list in Bind, how can I make it reload without losing Cache?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, access-control-list, rndc

I have two ACL's, one expired, and one authorized. When I make a change to the ACL and try:

```
rndc reload
```

and

```
rndc reconfig
```

I do not see that the ACL was refreshed. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a quicker DNS Setup?](http://serverfault.com/questions/633337/what-is-a-quicker-dns-setup)

Comment: I'll take that part out of the other question, as it was less direct.